# striim - Connection Not Made: 1

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb, striim

striim running on local. I am trying to flow data from SQL running in Azure VM to Azure CosmosDB SQL API. But i am getting above error when testing connection. However it is connecting while adding source from template

Answer (score 0):

yes, this is a known bug, which will be fixed in next release.
it does not affect the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

What is the connection string used?. Did you try to start the application?. As long as the app starts you shouldn't worry about the test connection.